# Solidity mapping value storage size

Tags: solidity

When storing values in mappings in solidity, will it take the same storage size for uint8 and uint16? I.E all uint's take up the same storage space?

Comment: Yes because uint8 and uint16 both fit into one storage slot (32 bytes), which is the smallest storage size for a mapping's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for storage space, but I tried measuring gas usage, and uint256 actually used less gas to push values onto a mapping than uint8. Using the following contract, uint256 cost 46707 gas and uint8 cost 46944 gas. Reading also cost less for uint256.

This is the contract I used to test:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Test {

    mapping(int => uint8) one;
    mapping(int => uint256) two;
    int counter = 0;

    function pushOne() public {
        one[counter++] = 1;
    }

    function pushTwo() public {
        two[counter++] = 256;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's costs more for smaller types  because when you use a smaller sized uint, solidity does an extra bitwise & to clear the top bits.

Answer (score 5):

It depends how you do it.

If you do

```
mapping(bytes32 = uint8) tinyInts;
mapping(bytes32 => uint16) biggerInts;
```

It will cost more than

```
struct IntStruct {
  uint8 tinyInt;
  uint16 biggerInt;
}

mapping(bytes32 => IntStruct) intStructs;
```

... because a 32-byte word is the smallest addressable slot in storage. In the first instance, there are two different references to two different 32-byte words (so 64 bytes, total). Indeed, both values could be `uint256` precision and this would actually be marginally cheaper because of the extra work involved in packing/unpacking lower precision numbers.

In the second, a single 32-byte word would accommodate both values with room to spare in a 32-byte word. Since storage the biggest expense, the more compact structure is cheaper.

Mappings point to objects that are composed of 32-byte words in all cases.

Hope it helps.